# Issue with alignment of text box and bootstrap label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having hard time figuring out how to fix a small alignment issue as shown in the fiddle. The text box and 'R' bootstrap label is not aligned on the top.

https://jsfiddle.net/haribalaji/p7Louzq9/

```css
.inline-form-control
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}

.labelClass
{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
}
.label-primary {
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
.label {
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
Here is the code

<code>
<form>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="adrTerm"><span>Adverse Reaction Term</span><span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
   <div class="field"><input type="text" name="adrTerm" class="inline-form-control form-control" placeholder="Enter the ADR Term Name" value="" tabindex="1"><span class="labelClass label label-primary">R</span>
   <div class="input"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
</code>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, JSFIDDLE is blocked here. But I can see you are not following the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). Don't put a `row` class inside a form.  Notice that `.form-group` groups one label with one input. Do not use absolute positioning as the answer already provided suggests. I'm sure that would be considered a hack.

Comment: Where is your question?  And what do you mean by `The text box and 'R' bootstrap label is not aligned on the top.` Further, your fiddle does not include the Bootstrap resources. If you still are looking for an answer, I would suggest cleaning up this question and making it clearer. Otherwise, you should delete it.

Comment: hi Karl, Did you run the code snippet? See that the 'R' button looks small and not aligned with the top / bottom of the text box to its left. Do you have any bootstrap 3 based styling fix?

Comment: I did run the code snippet and the jsfiddle. The snippet in this question is never going to work since the Bootstrap classes are not linked in. Ditto with the jsfiddle, you've not linked to the Bootstrap CSS. There are a lot of issues with your markup. Look at the fiddle, the closing form tag is in red. That means there is an error in the markup.  Why are there 2 inputs? Is that intentional? If so, where are you trying to line up the label. Relative to the inputs? Between them? Bottom line, the markup is too complex, and your question does not explicitly state how you want the alignment.

Comment: There is only one input element. I am trying to align the textbox with <span class="labelClass label label-primary">R</span>. The 'R' letter label should be as big as the text box (height) and width as much as the height.

Comment: My mistake. I looked at this `<div class="input"></div>` along with this `<input type="text"...` too quickly and thought there were 2 inputs. Nonetheless, you still should simplify the markup. It's much more complex than is needed and if you are going to use `jsfiddle` as a learning tool (an excellent idea IMO), then you need to link the Bootstrap CSS as a resource. If you create a form, with one `form-group` containing the label and the input and nothing more, no custom classes, no nothing (other than the `span` for color), and then still have problems, I'm sure I or someone will help out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated link to [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p7Louzq9/2/)

```
.labelClass
{
   display: inline-block;
   position:absolute;//added
}
.label {
    display: inline;
    padding:0 0.6em;//changed
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.8;//changed
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

Make label position absolute,
Removed unnecessary padding,
Changed line height of label.

Use **input group add-on** of bootstrap if you are using.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/

Answer (score 0):

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7Louzq9/6/) demonstrates the "R" label being the same height as the input and aligned to its right.

As mentioned in the comments earlier, the markup needed to be much simpler:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="adrTerm" class="col-xs-12 control-label text-left">Adverse Reaction Term<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-xs-11">
        <input type="text" name="adrTerm" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the ADR Term Name" value="" tabindex="1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label class="text-center rLabel">R</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And also, very little custom CSS is required:

```
.container {
  margin: 10px
}

.rLabel {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  margin-left: -30px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 80%;
}
```

This still may not give you exactly what you want. For example, you may not care for how the "R" label will change width when the window is resized. If so, change the width in the `.rLabel` class to a fixed width.

Note how the Bootstrap styles are added to the fiddle as an external resource.

Also, note that the use of a container is required.